# PnP interface to view MySQL tables as spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, php, python, mysql

I have a dataset that is quickly outgrowing a spreadsheet. I would like to port this data to MySQL. I'm pretty well-versed with it, but my business partner may not be. Are there any plug-n-play apps/components that I can deploy and let my business partner see the tables as spreadsheets? I'm looking for something very quick & dirty since I don't need it to be fancy, just something where he could run some basic filtering and ordering operations and then the cut & paste out of it. I could code it myself, but something like this must exist already for MySQL.

I've used multiple tags on this because I am language agnostic on this.

Comment: mysql odbc connection -> link database into MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you can use [gelsheet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gelsheet/?source=pdlp) or [DHTMLX Spreadsheet](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSpreadsheet/), You can also look at the demo and see if [PHPMaker] is something like what you want, I constantly use and is a very simple and useful tool, with a couple of clicks and you have a form and a dynamic datagrid to display the information

Comment: Great answers. One of these should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) lets you browse the data, run queries on it, and export it to CSV, which you could then use in a real spreadsheet.  It is probably wisest to avoid doing anything on the server except export the data or a query result.

Comment: This is a good answer except that I dont think his SQL skills are up to snuff. I havent used this tool in a while, but if memory serves, it still requires a fair knowledge of SQL